# Simulate lag function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sliding-window

```
| time                | company | quote |
+---------------------+---------+-------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | GOOGLE  |    40 |
| 2012-07-02 21:28:05 | GOOGLE  |    60 |
| 2012-07-02 21:28:51 | SAP     |    60 |
| 2012-07-02 21:29:05 | SAP     |    20 |
```

How do I do a lag on this table in MySQL to print the difference in quotes, for example:

```
GOOGLE | 20
SAP    | 40
```

Comment: Are there only two per `company`? or is it variable?

Comment: I see you have two companies here, but are there only ever two rows per company? If so you can use `MAX() - MIN()` aggregates trivially. If there are more than 2 rows per `company`, it is more complicated.

Comment: I just need the latest two timestamp.. may be there are lot of entries for the same company but i just need to take the latest two time stamp and print the diff of quotes

Comment: If a company is represented by only one row, would you like to return that company in the results? If so, what difference should be returned for it?

Comment: And finally, what particular problem is this question about: how to return last two rows per company or how to calculate the difference between two rows? I don't think you should mix these two problems in a single question. You will likely get better quality answers if you ask two separate questions (in case you really need to solve both problems).

Comment: In your example, why isn't the result negative for one of the companies?  Google goes from 40 up to 60 whereas SAP goes from 60 down to 20.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b62e1/1/0  Or do you only want the absolute movement irrespective of direction (in which case take [`ABS(delta)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs))?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.I just want to present the delta for example it 20 for google ab -40 for Sap, but now its doing the reverse

Comment: Why, eggyal's suggestion returns those results exactly. What is the issue? (By the way, @eggyal, you should probably make that an answer.)

Comment: @AndriyM: I'm quite sure that there must be a better way than that (which involves a full table scan), but I'm struggling to see it.  I suppose one could take the group maximum twice and get something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e28e7/1/0 ... but that's so ugly and involves accessing the table 5 times -- can it really be the best option?  I was leaving it open in the hope that someone else might come along with something much more insightful!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is my favorite MySQL hack.

This is how you emulate the lag function:

```
SET @quot=-1;
select time,company,@quot lag_quote, @quot:=quote curr_quote
  from stocks order by company,time;
```

- `lag_quote` holds the value of previous row's quote. For the first row @quot is -1.
- `curr_quote` holds the value of current row's quote.

Notes:

1. `order by` clause is important here just like it is in a regular
   window function.
2. You might also want to use lag for `company` just to be sure that you are computing difference in quotes of the same `company`.
3. You can also implement row counters in the same way `@cnt:=@cnt+1`

The nice thing about this scheme is that is computationally very lean compared to some other approaches like using aggregate functions, stored procedures or processing data in application server.

EDIT:

Now coming to your question of getting result in the format you mentioned:

```
SET @quot=0,@latest=0,company='';
select B.* from (
select A.time,A.change,IF(@comp<>A.company,1,0) as LATEST,@comp:=A.company as company from (
select time,company,quote-@quot as change, @quot:=quote curr_quote
from stocks order by company,time) A
order by company,time desc) B where B.LATEST=1;
```

The nesting is not co-related so not as bad (computationally) as it looks (syntactically) :)

Let me know if you need any help with this.

Comment: I am getting error. DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.

Comment: Though the error does not indicate this, try enabling "allowMultiQueries". This is a connector paramenter. For JDBC connector, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html . Are you able to run it successfully from MySQL client?

Comment: You can also try executing the two statements individually but in the same session.

Comment: @javanx Hi, I'm the author of SQL Fiddle.  The error message you mention was actually a bug in the way I was handling certain types of MySQL queries.  Thanks to your message here, I recognized it as such and have worked out a solution that fixes it (see here, for example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f8a1/2).  Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me! But I don't understand the mechanism. Could you explain?

Comment: `@`symobol indicates that it is session variable. So `@quot` is a variable. `SET @quot=0` initializes it to 0. Imagine the rest of the query like a for loop that is iterrating through the result set. whenever you do `@quot:=x`, the value of current row's x column is copied into `@quot`. What is the difference between `SET @quot=something` and `@quot:=something` (notice the colon)? I don't know, that's how they want the syntax to be. When you use `SET` it does not expect a colon, when you just do `@variable_name = something`, it needs a colon before equal sign. so its `@quot:=something`.

Comment: Note the order colums/operations `@quot lag_quote, @quot:=quote curr_quote`. First I just read the value of `@quot` and name the column `lag_quote`. `@quot` is still holding the previously assigned value, i.e the previous row's `quote` value as we have not yet executed `@quot:=quote` for the current row.  Then we do  `@quot:=quote` whose output is the updated value of `@quot` i.e quote from the current row. And we name this column column as `curr_quote`

Comment: **NOTE** You have to keep the data type of the variable consistent with the type of data you are trying to lag. EG, if you want to accumulate a FLOAT field, you must initialize your variable as `@quot=0.0`, otherwise it will not work. Took me a minute to figure this out!

Answer (score 14):

From MySQL 8.0 and above there is no need to simulate `LAG`. It is natively supported,

> [Window Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) :
>
> Returns the value of expr from the row that lags (precedes) the current row by N rows within its partition. If there is no such row, the return value is default. For example, if N is 3, the return value is default for the first two rows. If N or default are missing, the defaults are 1 and NULL, respectively.

```
SELECT
     company,
     quote,
     LAG(quote) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY time) AS prev_quote
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8368c46ef03356e2778e8d21c898aaa)**

Answer (score 10):

To achieve the desired result, first you need to find the last and next to last timestamps for each company. It is quite simple with the following query:

```sql
SELECT c.company, c.mts, max(l.ts) AS lts
  FROM (SELECT company, max(ts) AS mts FROM cq GROUP BY company) AS c
  LEFT JOIN cq l
    ON c.company = l.company AND c.mts > l.ts
 GROUP BY c.company, c.mts;
```

Now you have to join this subquery with the original table to get the desired results:

```sql
SELECT c.company, l.quote, coalesce(l1.quote, 0),
       (l.quote - coalesce(l1.quote, 0)) AS result
  FROM (SELECT c.company, c.mts, max(l.ts) AS lts
      FROM (SELECT company, max(ts) AS mts FROM cq GROUP BY company) AS c
      LEFT JOIN cq l
        ON c.company = l.company AND c.mts > l.ts
     GROUP BY c.company, c.mts) AS c
  LEFT JOIN cq AS l ON l.company = c.company AND l.ts = c.mts
  LEFT JOIN cq AS l1 ON l1.company = c.company AND l1.ts = c.lts;
```

You can observe results on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85b5e/1).

This query is using only standard SQL capabilities and should work on any RDBMS.

Comment: Good answer, especially for people preparing for tech interviews since they often discourage using window functions.