# Retrieve the previous record and store to text boxes

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am working on a project in Visual Studio 2017 using C# which shows and saves test results as well as compare the current and previous records, although I created a trial solution file to simplify the tables.

One of the functions of it is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683055/how-to-best-retrieve-the-most-recent-previous-record-for-each-record) except I have this table in my service-based database `dtbTrial`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTest1]
(
    [TestNumber] NUMERIC(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [ParameterA] REAL NULL, 
    [ParameterB] REAL NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_tblTest1_tblTestMain] FOREIGN KEY ([TestNumber]) REFERENCES [tblTestMain]([TestNumber])
)
```

and intended to retrieve the previous record and put `ParameterA` and `ParameterB` of the previous record to its respective text boxes. The concerned table currently has three rows.

Using the linked question above, I tried to replicate it and run to my code on button click. I have tried two query strings based on the answers:

```
WITH dbo AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TestNumber ORDER BY TestNumber) row_num FROM tblTest1)
SELECT a.TestNumber,
a.ParameterA, (SELECT MAX(b.ParameterA) FROM dbo b WHERE b.TestNumber = a.TestNumber AND b.row_num < a.row_num) AS PrevParameterA,
a.ParameterB, (SELECT MAX (b.ParameterB) FROM dbo b WHERE b.TestNumber = a.TestNumber AND b.row_num < a.row_num) AS PrevParameterB
FROM dbo a  WHERE TestNumber = @testnumber"
```

and

```
SELECT TestNumber, ParameterA, LAG(ParameterA) OVER (PARTITION BY TestNumber ORDER BY TestNumber) PrevParameterA, ParameterB, LAG(ParameterB) OVER (PARTITION BY TestNumber ORDER BY TestNumber) PrevParameterB FROM tblTest1 WHERE TestNumber = @testnumber
```

then run the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testnumber", testNumberTextBox.Text);
                    con.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    textBox2.Text = (dr["PrevParameterA"].ToString());
                    textBox1.Text = (dr["PrevParameterB"].ToString());
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

The intended output did not actuate i.e. the text boxes remain null or of no value. I also tried running both to the dataset of the database and the following error appears:

> The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.

A beginner as I am, I'm at loss as how to fix it. What did I miss or what should I do to rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your table definition and code, you want to get the previous record of given testnumber. Then you don't need to use `over` or other any complex queries.

This query enough for you

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [tblTest1] WHERE TestNumber < @testnumber ORDER BY TestNumber DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028966/substitute-command-for-over-in-ssrs) there is a chance that including alias should fix your problem. Thus, your subquery will be looking something like this:

```
SELECT t.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TestNumber ORDER BY TestNumber) row_num 
FROM tblTest1 t
```

Comment: Using an alias still gives null text boxes but I might take note of using aliases when needed. Thanks.