# Query to See Count of ProductName against same ProductId

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]

How to write Sql Query to show Number of Names based on one Product Id.
For example in this example: For ProductId - 263, Count(Name) = 3

I would like to see

```
263 3
264 2 
265 10
266 0 (if null)
```

Comment: `select productid,count(name) from tablename group by productid` and how you know the next id like 266

Comment: That probably counts as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT productid, COUNT(*)
FROM products 
GROUP BY productid
```

It's not an exact answer, but it will return the number of occurrences of the productid for each unique productid. It may help you find your result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table of products, then you want a `left join`:

```
select p.productid, count(pn.productid)
from products p left join
     productnames pn
     on p.productid = pn.productid
group by p.productid;
```

Comment: Hi @gordonlinoff would you, please, take a time to look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33006952/460557) it is not related to this question but I think it worth to a specialist as yourself to take a look. The problem involve this two links [sqlfiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c77d8/7) and [sqlfiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c77d8/182) notice the last value on the `quantity_diff` column

Answer (score 0):

Pang.

I have written an answer using a CTE that will give you the count of all the names for each product that can easily be changed to COUNT the DISTINCT names.

```
   ;WITH    CTE_DISTINCT_NAMES
        AS (SELECT      --DISTINCT 
                        /* Uncomment "DISTINCT" above 
                           to include duplicate names 
                           in the COUNT
                           */
                        ProductId   
            ,           Name        
            FROM        TABLE1
            )
        SELECT      T.ProductId
        ,           COUNT(ISNULL(T.Name,'')) AS [COUNT(Name)]
        FROM        CTE_DISTINCT_NAMES AS T
        GROUP BY    T.ProductId
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCT_ID AS PID,
    COALESCE(COUNT(NAME), 0) AS CNT
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: SELECT PRODUCT_ID AS PID,ISNULL(COUNT(NAME),0) AS CNT FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID