# Substract different row values based on other column value

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to do almost same thing as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12310322/5597724) but I can't seem to generate my objective after I tried to alter that to my case.

```
   id, type, time, amount
   ------------
   18, depo, 2020-02-02 10:13:00, 30
   17, full, 2020-02-02 10:12:00, 100
   16, full, 2020-02-01 15:12:00, 100
   15, full, 2020-02-01 13:12:00, 100
```

All I need is to SUM() all group by date, I've done this.

```
SELECT sum(amount) amount, DATE(time) day 
  FROM `payment` 
 GROUP BY DATE(time), type 
 ORDER BY day, type DESC
```

It returns two same dates

```
   70, 2020-02-02
   100, 2020-02-02
   200, 2020-02-01
```

The operation I need is full minus by (-) depo so on 2020-02-02 I will get 70. Same with other dates. I'm thinking to assign all the data to PHP arrays butt is there an "easier" workaround so I could just call the data straight from the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @danish-khan-I yes I need the amount for 'full' type minus by 'depo' type for same date. Unnormalized ik.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional (`case..when` clause) within aggregation :

```
SELECT sum(case when type = 'depo' then - amount else amount end) amount, DATE(time) day 
  FROM `payment` 
 GROUP BY DATE(time), type 
 ORDER BY day, type DESC
```

Comment: It still return two same dates but the result is easier to manipulate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two lines because of the group by clause : `group by type` : one line for depo and one line for full, if the only lines you need to aggregate are lines `where type in ('full', 'depo')`, then, you can just group by Date (I based my answer on @Barbaros-Özhan answer)

```
SELECT sum(case when type = 'depo' then - amount else amount end) amount, DATE(time) day 
  FROM `payment` 
  WHERE type IN ('full', 'depo')
 GROUP BY day 
 ORDER BY day
```

I have also removed the ORDER BY type, since you said all you need is SUM by DATE.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=97b2815ed3be38d28a65c07b95949870)