# creating a column at runtime while runnin the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to create a column at run time  (RANK of salary ) ,which depends on the value of a salary column from one table(COLLAGE ) and this salary  is associated with an employee table. Can you suggest how to generate it . The RANK column will contain the value based on salary i.e if the salary is highest than RANK is 1 ... in ascending order.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please attach your full structure of tables that are needed to perform this task including foreign keys to match the data. Also, decide which DBMS you are using. Answers would be different regarding your engine. Is it Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: I think you are wanting a SQL statement that joins your `COLLAGE` and `Employee` tables and ranks the `Salary` for each employee. Not so much to create a column at runtime.. but rather write a SQL statement that will return the record set you need. Also, you need to specify which DBMS you are using. Oracle and MySQL are two very different databases.

Comment: If you are having to create columns in your table at runtime, this should be a big flag regarding your design.

Comment: Hi i have table collage in which collage(COLLAGE_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,DEPARTMENT ) is present and EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID,SALARY,AGE ) now i need to create RANK while run time which entirely depends on salary. Here EMPLoYEE_ID is the   foreign key .

Comment: MYSQL server am using .

Answer (score 0):

This would get you id of your employee, their salary and a rank column.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    @currentRank := @currentRank + 1 AS rank_of_salary
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.employee_id,
        e.salary
    FROM      
        collage c
        INNER JOIN employee e ON c.employee_id = e.employee_id
    ) t, (SELECT @currentRank := 0) r
ORDER BY salary
```

`(SELECT @currentRank := 0)` initializes a variable so that you do not need separate `SET` statement.

For each row `@currentRank` variable is being increased and stored in `rank_of_salary` column. It's actually more a `row_number` equivalent I believe. Proper ordering of this rank is maintained by sorting the output with `ORDER BY salary` clause.

Comment: Will the current rank will be automatically will get increased ?

Comment: Added some explanation. It will be automatically increased for each row.
No, it can't be done using CASE statement since for that you'd need previous value to compare it with. You can also extend this query using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql

Comment: See if it works for you, you can also accept/upvote the answer if you find it useful. Here's a link to provide you with information of how to do it : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work