# MySQL query to find available slots between two time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called booked meeting and following is the table structure

meeting table

```
id | meeting_name | from_time  | to_time | date
```

Following are the structure

```
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `meeting_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `bookings` (`id`, `meeting_name`, `from_time`, `to_time`, `date`) VALUES(
(1, 'meeting1', '09:00:00', '10:30:00', '2018-07-26'),
(2, 'meeting2', '11:40:00', '12:25:00', '2018-07-26');
(3, 'meeting3', '03:40:00', '04:25:00', '2018-07-26'););
```

and here i am trying find available slots between two time  suppose if i enter `from time` as `10:00:00` and `to time` as `01:00:00` then it should return all the meetings between this time and need to find out available timing between them

I am new to mysql so tried few queries but didn't got expected result

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bookings` 
WHERE bookings.from_time>="10:00:00" and bookings.to_time<="01:00:00"


SELECT * 
FROM `bookings` 
WHERE bookings.from_time>="10:00:00" or
    bookings.to_time<="10:00:00" or
    bookings.from_time>="01:00:00" or
    bookings.to_time<="01:00:00"
```

Expected Result 
if i pass time between 10:00:00.00 to 13:00:00 then it should return

[image]

and also available slots like

```
10:31:00 to 11:39:00
12.26 to 03:49:00
```

Comment: Do you want a list of meetings between the two times, or available empty times as your question suggests?

Comment: Also, why not store the start/end times as timestamps or date/times? Are the times in 24 hour format or 12 hour format?

Comment: @SloanThrasher. I need list of meetings booked between two time .and if any slots free avail then i need display time avail to book

Comment: @SloanThrasher.if that makes result i can . i am new to mysql so done like this.any help and correction in table is acceptable.thanks

Comment: The first is easy and you could simply use BETWEEN. The second isn't as simple, and would be a separate query.

Comment: @SloanThrasher.two queries or sub queries also fine if it doesnt produce result

Comment: `SELECT * FROM bookings  WHERE bookings.from_time>="10:00:00" and to_time <="13:00:00"` // "01:00:00" means 1 am . I think you should format your time accordingly

Comment: @MadhanM.it will return only one record  11.40 to 12 not that 9 to 10.30

Comment: Do you need to satisfy either of the time? from_time > 10 am or to_time < 1pm ?

Comment: @MadhanM.yes.also 1pm i can change to 13

Comment: Why not or Query then ? `SELECT * 
FROM bookings 
WHERE bookings.from_time>="10:00:00" or to_time <="13:00:00"`

Comment: i tried but nto retuning as expected result

Comment: you should specify your expected result as well to let us help you quickly

Comment: @Kunal.updated question

Comment: @vision how about  `SELECT * 
FROM bookings 
WHERE (bookings.from_time>="10:00:00" AND  to_time <="13:00:00") OR (from_time<="13:00:00" AND  to_time >="10:00:00" )`

Comment: Store date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 0):

To find all meetings with at least some of their time within the defined time slot (from 10:00h to 13:00h) you should do

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bookings` 
WHERE bookings.from_time<="13:00:00" -- end of time slot
AND   bookings.to_time>=  "10:00:00" -- start of time slot
```

I hope that I understood the question properly with respect to the end time. I prefer to use the 24h notation. For completeness you should also check that the `date` value is identical to the investigated time slot.

Try out the little demo here: http://rextester.com/LNUD45826

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I used 24h format, you should too.

Here's your data enriched by one additional day, to show, that query will encapsulate gaps between meetings within the same day:

```
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `meeting_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `bookings` (`id`, `meeting_name`, `from_time`, `to_time`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'meeting1', '09:00:00', '10:30:00', '2018-07-25'),
(2, 'meeting2', '11:40:00', '12:25:00', '2018-07-25'),
(3, 'meeting3', '03:40:00', '04:25:00', '2018-07-25'),
(1, 'meeting4', '09:00:00', '10:30:00', '2018-07-26'),
(2, 'meeting5', '11:40:00', '12:25:00', '2018-07-26'),
(3, 'meeting6', '03:40:00', '04:25:00', '2018-07-26');
```

And here's your query, it's easy with `LAG` function implemented in SQL Server, here we have to imitate it ([here's how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql) - it will help you understand the query)

```
select @start := cast('10:00:00' as time), @end := cast('13:00:00' as time),
       @time := cast(null as time), @date := cast(null as date);

select date, to_time_lag, from_time, gap_between_meetings from (
  select id,
         meeting_name,
         from_time,
         @time to_time_lag,
         to_time,
         @date date_lag,
         case when @date = date then timediff(from_time, @time) end gap_between_meetings,
         @time := to_time,
         date,
         @date := date
  from bookings
  where from_time between @start and @end
     or to_time between @start and @end
  order by date, from_time
) a where gap_between_meetings is not null
```

Comment: This is good, but I think you can go further . Date and time should be stored as a single entity