# Calculate Days difference from Datetime previous row

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a log_file table that I created with Created_at as datetime column , I need to get days between the rows by created_at

```
select id,DATE(created_at), datediff( created_at, prev_date) as diff
from (select t.*,
         (select DATE(t2.created_at)
          from log_file t2
          where t2.id = t.id and
                DATE(t2.created_at) <  DATE(t.created_at)
          order by  t2.created_at desc
          limit 1
         ) as prev_date
  from log_file t
 )  t
```

but its give me Null in `diff`

```
    id DATE(created_at) diff
     2 2019-01-16       NULL
     3 2019-01-19       NULL
     4 2019-01-21       NULL
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 8+, and you also don't want to use session variables, then a correlated subquery is one way to go here.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.created_at,
    DATEDIFF(t1.created_at,
             (SELECT t2.created_at FROM log_file t2
              WHERE t2.created_at < t1.created_at
              ORDER BY t2.created_at DESC LIMIT 1)) AS diff
FROM log_file t1;
```

You were on the right track, but the `WHERE` clause in your subquery has an incorrect added condition:

```
where t2.id = t.id
```

Remove it, and your current code might even work as is.

Comment: I'm curious, how would you have done it using session variables?

Comment: @Cid Have a look at [Simulate lag function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql).  I find those queries to be painful to write, and I don't write them often, hence I offered the above solution (which the OP was already using for the most part).