# How can I create new column in sql based on previous date?

Tags: sql

```
Col A         
1 Jan
2 Jan
3 Jan
5 Jan
6 Jan
```

Output

```
Col A      Col B
1 Jan    NULL
2 Jan    1 Jan
3 Jan    2 Jan
5 Jan    3 Jan
6 Jan    5 Jan
```

Comment: CTE with LAG() function

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `LAG()` as suggested by @Akina

```
WITH D AS (
SELECT A FROM YOUR_TABLE 
) 
SELECT A, LAG(A, 1) OVER(ORDER BY A DESC)
FROM D
```

*EDIT*
i see you are in mysql just now, you can try with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql) as well

Comment: Need to remove 0 from LAG, i.e., LAG(A,1). There are some other columns as well, so I used partition in OVER () and it worked. Thanks !!

Comment: yeew good! maybe accept the answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the window function `LAG()`.

```
SELECT *,
  LAG(col_a) OVER (ORDER BY col_a)
FROM t;
```

Demo: [`db<>fidldle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=70c083ed4756a6eba61e6c1a1329b977)

Answer (score 0):

WITH D AS (
SELECT date FROM table
)
SELECT date, LAG(date, 1) OVER(ORDER BY date)
FROM D