# How to select only the values that are arranged in order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySql 5.7 and a table "FizzBuzz"

| ID | Name | Sort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | 1 |
| 2 | Bar | 2 |
| 3 | Baz | 5 |
| 4 | Quux | 6 |
| 5 | Xyzzy | 7 |
| 6 | Plugh | 9 |

I need to get the records that follow each other in the sort field before the first increment break.

For example,

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM FizzBuzz
WHERE sort >= 1 and /* some */
```

should return only: Foo and Bar

And

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM FizzBuzz
WHERE sort > 2 and /* some */
```

should return only: Baz, Quux and Xyzzy

How can this be done?

Comment: I reckon that this problem will be tough to handle on MySQL 5.7.  Any chance you can upgrade to MySQL 8+ ?

Comment: Nope. unfortunately.
I can roughly imagine how to do this on Mysql 8+, but not on 5.7

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, thanks

Comment: What do you think about my solution below, are there spots for improvement according to your experience or would you have attempted a different path? @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    SET @rn=0;
    SET @rn2=0;
    
    select T.* from
    (
      select ID, Name, Sort, @rn:=@rn+1 row_number, sort-@rn as cont_num_group
      from FizzBuzz
     ) T
    where T.sort>=1
    and T.cont_num_group =
    (select T2.cont_num_group from
    (
      select sort,@rn2:=@rn2+1 row_number, sort-@rn2 as cont_num_group
      from FizzBuzz 
     ) T2
     where T2.sort>=1 order by T2.sort limit 1
    )
    order by T.sort;
```

The idea is to find the difference between the `Sort` field and `Row Number`,  all rows with the same difference will be in an continuous order.

I used `select T.*` to show all derived fields so you can understand how the query works, you may replace it with `select  T.Id, T.name`.

See a demo from **[here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c2qvz1T42WDpEAaVmMfk8d/0)**.

Comment: @j.Doe, You are welcome. Actually, the complexity of this query raised from the nature of the problem, we are trying to select rows according to a derived field values which we can not predict. So we need to call the query twice, one to select rows and one to set the value of our condition. I am not saying that this is the only way to solve the problem, maybe someone else have a simple one. At the end, we are trying to help each other and it's up to you to accept the answer or wait for another one. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 5.7, you can use the following approach for this problem:

- self join your table on `t1.ID = t2.ID-1` (you're matching consecutive rows)
- generate a row number for each non-consecutive row (`@num := @num + 1`)
- match your preferred number in a subquery (`parts = <your_preferred_number>`).

```
SET @num = 1;

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT t1.*, 
             CASE WHEN t1.Sort <> t2.Sort+1 THEN @num := @num+1
                  WHEN t2.Sort IS NULL      THEN 1
                  ELSE @num END AS parts
      FROM      tab t1
      LEFT JOIN tab t2 
             ON t1.ID-1 = t2.ID) cte
WHERE parts = <your_preferred_number>
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bULe11reatXuryRdSUDD2j/7).

Comment: Look like good, but work only for `cte.rn=1`. If set 2/4/8 it's breaks

Comment: No, I meant it doesn't work. See this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c76c2cac5bcbf4601f30bfef65a4177e).  The solution does not suit me, but the result is correct

Comment: nope, it's not the same result

Comment: Ahmed made the right solution, but the request is very complicated, I would like it to be a little simpler

Comment: What about this one? @j.Doe

Comment: `LEAST(4, @num)` does not work as expected

Comment: Now you can remove it and use just `4`, and in general the value of your choice.

Comment: `cte.rn = 4` still not working

Comment: There's no `cte.rn = 4` (?). If you intend `parts = 4` then it really depends on what you expect to happen. Given that in your table there's no 4th discontinuation of numbers, the output is empty.

Comment: yes, ofcourse `parts = 4`. The search should work from any position (any sort number), as in Ahmed's solution

Comment: @j.Doe & lemon Assigning & reading the same user variable in the same select statement is explicitly undefined behaviour, see the manual re those parts of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you want check the order sequence in MySql? You can achieve it like following using Lag() function:

[MySQL Window Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag)

```
Select * from (SELECT ID, LAG([id],1) OVER (ORDER BY [ID]  ) as PreviousRow
From FizzBuzz)tb1 where  PreviousRow - ID < 1
```

I will suggest use programming way if you need more complicate logical checking instead of using SQL

Comment: The OP appears to be bound to using MySQL 5.7, in which case your query won't work.

Comment: It's work only in Mysql 8+. I want check this in Mysql because there can be a lot of records

Comment: IF your MySQL <8.0  ,you need set variable to hold the value for comparison,  Pls refer this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql